# How do I check for all entries that has a certain bit/flag/mask in them

Tags: mysql, sql, bit-manipulation, flags, azerothcore

Basically, I want to know if there is a query for finding bit masks within a column. For example, I want to find every entry with `0x00200` even though they might have several more flags.

Comment: This question is too general. Be more specific. "Query" usually implies you're working with a database. Which database? You do not expect that any database has the same query to solve your problem?

Comment: Ah, thought I added it lol, this is why I shouldn't split stuff in DMs and questions xD

Yea MySQL, so a database yea. Sorry about that =)

Comment: Then add "MySQL" to the keywords and, perhaps, to the title,  to attract attention of those who may know the answer.  I came across your question by chance, normally I view only those that contain my favorite keywords (SQL is not among them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a `@flag` value that you want to find for a certain column, for example value `2` from the `npcflag` column of the `creature_template` table , try the following:

```sql
SET @flag = 2;

SELECT `entry`, `name`, `npcflag`
FROM `creature_template` 
WHERE `npcflag` & @flag = @flag;
```